# Explain patent data set in Hadoop example

Tags: hadoop

I am currently reading Hodoop in action book and the most important example in the book is

```
4.1 Getting the patent data set
```

I am trying to get some CSV files [from this link](http://www.nber.org/patents/.)  and I am unable to do that all I can download is come .zip files which contains tpt files. the books says that there are some csv files which I can not get. further more I am unable to understand "The patent citation data" 
please if someone read this book and have some understanding of this example please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the table where the download links are, there are 3: the plain txt, a .tpt zipped file and an ASCII csv zipped file, the one in the right. The 2 files you need for the examples are: [acite75_99](http://www.nber.org/patents/acite75_99.zip) and [apat63_99](http://www.nber.org/patents/apat63_99.zip)

The first file contains only two fields, the first one is the id of a patent that cites the patent with the id of the second field. As for the second file, it contains more information about each patent: grant year, country...